# How do I post the contents of a form to MongoDB using JS, Node, and Express

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, mongodb

I've been trying to post a form to a cluster in Mongo by using a router.  I can post data from the backend via a VSCode extension, but any attempts I make at trying to have users post using the form do not work.

Here is the form I have in my index.html file

```html
<form action="http://localhost:3000/users/create" method="POST">
    <div>
      <label for="fName">First Name</label>
      <input type="text" name="fName" id="fName" required>
    </div>

    <div>
      <label for="lName">Last Name</label>
      <input type="text" name="lName" id="lName" required>
    </div>

    <div>
      <label for="userEmail">Email</label>
      <input type="email" name="userEmail" id="userEmail" required>
    </div>

    <div>
      <label for="userName">Username</label>
      <input type="text" name="userName" id="userName" required>
    </div>

    <div>
      <label for="password">Password</label>
      <input type="password" name="password" id="password" required>
    </div>

    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    <button type="reset" name=rst>Reset</button>
  </form>
```

This is my server.js file

```js
require('dotenv').config();

const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

mongoose.connect(process.env.DATABASE_URL, {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true
});
const db = mongoose.connection;
db.on('error', (error) => console.error(error));
db.once('open', () => console.log('Connected to database'));

app.use(express.json());

const usersRouter = require('./routes/users');
app.use('/users', usersRouter);

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

app.listen(3000, () => console.log('Server has Started!'));
```

And finally, here's the router from the users.js file in my routes folder that handles posting

```js
//POST - Create a user
router.post('/create', async (req, res) => {
    const user = new User({
        fName: req.body.fName,
        lName: req.body.lName,
        userEmail: req.body.userEmail,
        userName: req.body.userName,
        password: req.body.password
    });
    try{
        const newUser = await user.save();
        res.status(201).json(newUser);
    } catch (err) {
        res.status(400).json({ message: err.message });
    }
});
```

I went to the user model I have and removed the 'required' property from all of the variables, and when I tried to post the form, an empty user with an ID was created and sent to the Mongo cluster.  This leads me to believe that the form itself simply isn't going anywhere.  When I add back the 'required' property, I get the following error message when I submit the form:

{"message":"User validation failed: fName: Path `fName` is required., lName: Path `lName` is required., userEmail: Path `userEmail` is required., userName: Path `userName` is required., password: Path `password` is required."}

I am unsure if I need to make edits/additions to either the server.js file or the router in the users.js file, and how to go about fixing this.

Comment: you need to configure `body-parser` module for your json data to be directly read from the request

Comment: https://www.tabnine.com/code/javascript/modules/body-parser

Comment: I put body-parser in my server.js file and the form now creates a user in mongo upon submission, thank you!